# permission denied with exec and composer

Tags: php, composer-php, exec

I tried to execute a function to update composer or not.
But, the result display that the permission is denied

my composer.json is in 777
my composer.lock is in 644

thakn you

```
public function update() {
  $cmd =  static::$root . ' composer update 2>&1';

  exec($cmd, $output);

  return $output;
}
```

result :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(59) "sh: 1: /home/www/demo/shop/: Permission denied" }
```

Comment: What is `static::$root`?  What user and group is running the php process executing `update()`?  What are the permissions and user/group ownership of `/home/www/demo/shop`, `/home/www/demo` and `/home/www`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that because there is a space before composer where `static::$root` is being prepended that you are specifying a path or env variable in `static::$root`.  This will not work as you cannot rely on composer being in the path.  You probably want to use something like `exec("/usr/bin/composer update", $output);` or `/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/php /path/to/composer.phar update` or some combination of the two commands.

Comment: You have right but now I have this message : Array ( [0] => sh: 1: /home/www/demo/shop/composer: not found ) 127

Comment: There is clearly no composer script at that location.  Where is composer installed?  The installation location is not where composer.json is located.  Run `which composer` to figure out where you installed it. You probably also want `cd  /home/www/demo/shop/ && ` before the reset of the command so that you are running it form the correct working directory.

Comment: I tried this :       
exec( '/usr/bin/composer ' . static::$root . 'composer update 2>&1', $output, $return); 
 and the result is : Array ( [0] => [1] => In Factory.php line 648: [2] => [3] => The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to [4] => run correctly [5] => [6] => ) 1

Comment: based on that exec command, you are trying to run this: `/usr/bin/composer /home/www/demo/shop/composer update 2>&1`  Do you have a good understanding of how to use the CLI?

Comment: Same result, No, for me it's new, look some informations and try to find a solution to use composer without to make a online command to update, install and eventually remove

Comment: if I add this : putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . BASE_DIRECTORY . 'External/vendor/bin/composer');  the result is : Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Command "/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/composer" is not defined. [3] => [4] => ) 1

Comment: COMPOSER_HOME is one of the env variables the composer command will look at to locate the composer.json file. You need an absolute path to the composer script file, probably /usr/bin/composer and you need to set that env variable or use cd to change dir to the folder with the composer.json file in it.  Composer does not have a flag or argument for the composer.json file.